# How to record what processes start, and when, causing game to minimize or freeze

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

I believe since switching from an AMD radeon to an Nvidia graphics card, I have been having my games randomly minimize. In the case of 2K/Borderlands games... they just freeze unless I hit ESC immediately after seeing a screen hiccup.

So my question is, is there something in like sysinternals that I can use to monitor/record when and what processes have started? I am thinking that figuring out which process is the culprit may allow me to track down and remove the source of the problem.

Currently running:

- Win7 x64
- intel i7 970 CPU
- Gigabyte X58A-UD3R mobo
- 24 GB DDR3 RAM
- Nvidia Geforce GTX980

As usual, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is, its called _Process Monitor_, from Windows Sysinternals. You can find it here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx